# How to implement fully custom oAuth 2.0 with Core PHP (NO Google, Facebook, etc)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm looking for a sample code that could help me in implementing fully **custom code of oAuth 2.0 in Core PHP**.

I've Googled entire web but all are referring to third-party authentications like Google, Facebook, GitHub, etc.

Is there **any specific method to create oAuth Token by self**? Or I've to rely on some library?

Comment: Isn't a point of OAuth to rely on external identity providers? Or more like - specialized identity providers?

Comment: Apologies! What do you mean by that?

BTW can I create my own oAuth token? If yes, what are its necessary needs?